# Problem with ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 7.0 and fixed in 9.0.1**

---

The following line works fine:

```
ContourPlot3D[2 x - y == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
             ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> False]
```

But when I bind the equation `2 x - y == 0` to a variable `eq`:

```
eq = 2 x - y == 0
ContourPlot3D[eq, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
              ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> False]
```

it fails. I also noticed that values are assigned to variables x and y after executing ContourPlot3D. There's something that I don't understand about workings of `ContourPlot`. Could anyone explain what's going on and how should I pass the equation in a variable?

**UPDATE**

As **m_goldberg** wrote in his answer, in a bug-free Mathematica it is not necessary to defer evaluation so `eq = 2 x - y == 0` works fine. The call to `Evaluate` is still required. But it seems to me that `eq` and `2x - y == 0` should evaluate to the same expression:

```
In[33]:= eq === 1 + 2 x == 0
Out[33]= True
```

So what's difference between these two expressions, which causes them to behave differently in `ContourPlot3D`? How can I see this difference in Mathematica environment?

Comment: I am proactively affixing the bugs tag in regard to the latter part of the question.  Anyone who disagrees (with reason) is free to remove it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think this is fair enough. Evidently WRI agreed since this is fixed in version 9--no more assignments on `x` and `y`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Could you explain (or refer to a proper doc) for those of us still living on previous versions of the Universe?

Comment: @belisarius sorry, I can't. As you know, WRI doesn't make their complete list of fixes in each release public, so I have nothing to refer to. Suffice to say that, though, the behavior of this example is what one would expect as of version 9.0.1 (I didn't test 9.0.0).

Comment: @OleksandrR. That new Universe is very similar to the old one :). Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yep. V8.0 also gives the "unexpected" result

Comment: @belisarius thanks; tags adjusted.

Comment: It is also in version 9.0.0

Comment: Regarding your penultimate question, `eq` only becomes `2x-y==0` when it is evaluated. Before evaluation `eq` has head `Symbol` (and `2x-y==0` has head `Equal`). `ContourPlot3D` has the `HoldAll` attribute, so `eq` is passed to it in unevaluated form. My guess is that when `ContourPlot3D` tests its first argument to see if it's of the form `a==b`, it does so without evaluating it, and so ends up treating `eq` as a numerical function rather than an equality. Certainly a `Trace` shows `eq` being sampled at various points in the volume (almost all of which evaluate to `False` of course).

Comment: @SimonWoods in v11.0.0, `Attributes@ContourPlot3D` returns `{Protected, ReadProtected}`, i.e. there are no `HoldAll`. But one still needs `Evaluate`, is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be noted that in V9.0.1 this problem has been fixed; that is,

```
Clear@eq

eq = 2 x - y == 0;
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@eq, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> False]
```

works as expected.

Comment: Do you need to use Evaluate if there's no deferred assignment?

Comment: @Max. Yes, it is necessary. Not even `Evaluated -> True` works.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is very simple  :)

```
  eq = 2 x - y == 0
```

evaluates to `False`.

To make it work, simply defer the evaluation:

```
  eq := 2 x - y == 0
  ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@eq, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
                ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! That worked. But I still don't understand something. First, why does `eq = 2 x - y == 0` evaluate to `false`? And second, how do values from ContourPlot3D get assigned to x and y? I assume these two questions are related, but cannot figure out how.

Comment: I disagree with the saying that `eqn` evaluates to `False`. Not like `SameQ`, it will keep the form as it is when kernel doesn't know the answer. The problem is the attributes of `ContourPlot3D`; it seems hold the arguments, but in v11.0.0, it doesn't have `HoldAll`. I haven't checked other versions. Is this a bug?